# Get the middle of all bins from plt.hist

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have made a histogram with `plt.hist()` and I now have an array with the bins in this form:

```
bins = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # n edges
```

Is there a easy way to get the middle from these bins? End result would be a list with `n - 1` centers like:

```
centers = [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5] # n - 1 centers
```

I don't know beforehand what the bins will be.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work good enough:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y = [(x[i] + x[i + 1]) / 2 for i in range(len(x[:-1]))]
print(y)
# [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [136]: bins = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [137]: centers = 0.5*(bins[:-1] + bins[1:])

In [138]: centers
Out[138]: array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions all demonstrate the same idea, i.e. find the average of neighboring points in the array. Here's another way to skin the cat:

```
import numpy

def centers(bins):
    return np.diff(bins) / 2 + bins[:-1]

bins = np.arange(0, 7)
print(centers(bins))
# array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5])
```